# Routing in dot net core with more than one parameter

Tags: c#, .net-core, asp.net-core-routing

Please let me know the exact method to ensure that correct parameters are sent in URL in order to navigate correctly in dot net core.

```
    [HttpGet("{id},{id2}",Name ="Edit")]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public ActionResult Edit(int id, int id2)
    {
        return Ok(3);
    }

    [HttpGet("{id}")]
    public string Get(int id)
    {
        return "value";
    }
```

When i try navigating to following url:

```
/api/test/Edit?id=1&id2=4
```

it gets navigated to the other method `Get` and returns value as string.

Startup.cs file has the following contents

```
app.UseMvcWithDefaultRoute();
```

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that the correct route templates are applied to the actions

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class TestController: Controller {

    //GET api/test/edit?id=1&id2=4
    [HttpGet("Edit")]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public ActionResult Edit(int id, int id2) {
        //...

        return Ok(3);
    }

    //GET api/test/5
    [HttpGet("{id}")]
    public string Get(int id) {
        return "value";
    }
}
```

#### Reference [Routing to controller actions in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/routing)

Answer (score 0):

.Net Core 3.1.3

In the Startup.Configure Method:

```
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
     {
          endpoints.MapControllers();
     });
```

Controller Annotation: `[Route("[controller]/[action]")]`

Action Method Annotation: `[HttpGet("{param1:int}/{param2:int}")]`

From the postman: `https://localhost:5001/controller/action/param1/param2`

Hope this helps!